# Browser showing plain text instead of html in windows

Tags: html

I am a new learner. I created a txt file and named it index.html then edited it in Atom. In Atom's html preview, everything was showing without any problem. But when I saved it and opened it in chrome, it showed everything in plain text instead of html. I am using windows 10. If anyone knows what is happening kindly please help.

Here are the images from my browser and atom html preview:

Atom:
[image: Atom screenshot]

Browser:
[image: browse screenshot]

Thank you all in advance

Comment: It clearly shows in your browser and Atom screenshots that the file is named `index.html.txt`, ie. not an html file.

Comment: Look in the browser's address bar. It shows `index.html.txt` not `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake and saved it as a text file. Save the file again as a .html file only.

Comment: I saved as index.html and cant see any txt in my folder. But the browser shows this. and I don't know if there is any other way to solve this problem..

Comment: This error is quite common. When you are saving the file set the 'Save as Type' column to all files and then save the file with .html